# CSS: center elements inside <div> side by side

Tags: html, css

i've been trying all night to center this elements without having them stacked on each other:

[image]

I've tried floating them to the left it works, but, they stick to the left side no matter what i did.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="center pages clearfix">
    <buuton class="center page-number">1</buuton>
    <buuton class="center page-number">2</buuton>
    <buuton class="center page-number">3</buuton>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

.page-number {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.47);
}
```

Comment: what you trying to archive? 3 blocks align in center in 1 line?

Comment: From what you've said, it's clear that you don't want the elements to stick to the left, but where _do_ you want them to be?

Comment: @Math3w Yes, i want them to aligned in one line

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie in the center of the page

Comment: see my answer below, just update "display:block" to "display:inline-block" like the below updated css

Comment: you should center the div, which you do. then remove the "center" from each button, which is causing them to have margins and take up entire width.

Comment: @Aru, should apply text-align:center; for .center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just update "`display:block`" to "`display:inline-block`" like the below updated css

**updated css**

.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
}

```
.page-number {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.47);
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pqg8d1j/1/)

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work. I've just checked the demo, its still on the left side.

Comment: also need to remove 'center' class from buttons

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Removing the `center` class does not make any different

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/uo23L4n4/

use inline-block instead of block for the buttons.

use text-align:center

```
<button class=" page-number">1</button>

.center {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
text-align: center;
}

.page-number {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
width: 28px;
height: auto;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47);
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.5;
text-align: center;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.47);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mark up to a list, makes it very easy to do this.

```
 <ul class="center pages clearfix">
    <li><buuton class="center page-number">1</buuton></li>
    <li><buuton class="center page-number">2</buuton></li>
    <li><buuton class="center page-number">3</buuton></li>
 </ul>
```

Use this css

```
 ul{
    list-style:none;
 }
 li{
   display:inline-block;
 }
```